# How many ways can rabbits be distributed so that there are always exactly two rabbits outside of both burrows?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In a certain area there are 20 different rabbits and two different burrows. Each burrow has the capacity to house all these rabbits, but it is possible that not all of these rabbits decide to enter one of these burrows. How many ways can rabbits be distributed so that there are always exactly two rabbits outside of both burrows?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: What is your **own** work beside copying the text of your exercice ?

Comment: Well, I am learnig about combinatorics and i know that the problem is related with permutations, my problem is that i can't do the conceptual step for solving it, i don't have much about "how" i can solve it

Comment: Now, Is it related with partitions? I consider that the problem is about the number of partitions of the set of 20 rabbits in 3 sets such that one of the three sets must have always three elements, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HINT*

Two rabbits can be chosen to be outside in $\,^{20}C_2$ ways

$18$ *distinct* rabbits are now left to be put in two *distinct* burrows, so each rabbit has two choices, and you should be able to figure out how many choices are there.

Now combine the two parts using multiplicative principle.

Comment: Thank you, so, it would be 190(2^18)

Comment: Yes, that's right